# fix data property name in gridview

Tags: c#, datagrid

I have  2 table :

table1: name, family, cityID
table2: cityID, cityName

I have a gridview that it's datasource is:
select * from table1, table2 where table1.cityID = table2.cityID

I disable autoCreatColumns

I add 3 columns to my datagrid.

in first column I fix the data property name to name
in second column I fix the data property name to family
but in third colum when I fix the data propery name to table2.cityName It dosent work...

I want to show the city name in third column.

Its an example but in fact, I have cityName in anouther table that I used, and if I use just cityName, makes error

can any body help me?
Thanks...

Comment: Without giving `table2.cityName` just give `cityName` as 3rd column's DataPropertyName.

Comment: which way you use to get datasource?
simple query, stored proc or entity framework?
There can be an an issue like
1) the column is renamed in selected set 
2) there is another column with this name in table1

Comment: Its an example but in fact, I have cityName in anouther table that I used, and if I use just cityName, makes error

Answer (score 0):

try to change 
select * from table1, table2 where table1.cityID = table2.cityID

**To**

select table1.name as Name,table1.family as Family,table2.cityName as City from table1, table2 where table1.cityID = table2.cityID

Comment: thanks for your answer, but Its an example, I have many columns that I cant rename all of them

Comment: okay.. then i just give some tips from my experience, if you use join in your query,select all probably is the wrong way. if you cant rename all you column, just try select them one by one..
hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,family,cityName from table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.cityID = table2.cityID
```

As you are doing inner joins with city ids on both tables..U will get matched Table IDs with name,citynames

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to write `table2.cityName`, just write `cityName` and it should work.

Comment: Its an example but in fact, I have cityName in anouther table that I used, and if I use just cityName, makes error

Comment: At a time you can bind one source to a Girdview for e.g. DataTable, try bringing all the columns in one source and then just use cityName.